# Issues with JQuery/AJAX Form Handling

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have two files. This is my main file - **index.php** which has javascript in the head, here's the javascript:

```
   <script
       src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
       type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script>
        $(function () {
            $('form#revisionnotes').on('submit', function(e) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'submits/updatenotes.php',
                    data: $('form').serialize(),
                    success: function () {
                        alert('You have successfully saved the revision notes.');
                    }
                });
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });     
    </script>
```

So when my form:

```
 <form id="revisionnotes" name="revisionnotes" method="post">
    <textarea style="width:100%;height:290px; padding:10px;" id="notes" > <?php echo $db->result("SELECT * FROM revision_notes", "notes");?></textarea><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>
</form>
```

From there in my **updatenotes.php** I was going to do a database INSERT, however that didn't work so I then tried adding a javascript alert to see if that'd work either:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        alert("hi");
</script>
```

And that didn't work either, I'm completely stumped. Could somebody please explain to  me where I'm going wrong? I've never used this type of form-submitting before.

Thanks.

Comment: You didnt close the first script-Tag.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about typos

Comment: You should try and use Firefox with Firebug. That would allow you to debug Javascript errors, follow form submissions, etc. . There's a similar Web Developer extension for Google Chrome, too.

Comment: @Doodlebunch Sorry that's my bad, that was already there in my actual code, however for some reason it didn't appear here.

Comment: @Iserni Yeah I've took a look at that and there's no errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not say *where* exactly the trouble lies, so this is an incomplete answer:

```
  $(function () {
        alert("Alpha - jQuery is called");
        $('#revisionnotes').on('submit', function(e) {
            alert("Bravo - submit received");
            var data = $(this).serialize();
            alert("Charlie - data serialized");
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'submits/updatenotes.php',
                data: data, // $('form').serialize(),
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    alert("Delta - POST submission succeeded");
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

The above should allow you to see where (if) the workflow fails to follow the plan.

At this point the POST should have been fired, and using Firebug or WebDev you should be able to inspect the results. Otherwise, temporarily convert the POST to GET, copy the URL and paste into another browser window.

Note: do not put Javascript in the POST-receiving script, since chances are that it won't be executed. You're not "going" to that page, just doing a submit; that's why you don't see your alert.

Ordinarily you would return some information from the submission page in JSON format and let `success()` extract it from the `data` variable. Note that "success" only means that the target script received the submission, **not** that it did handle it properly.

## Example of success function (and how to "talk" to it)

```
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    if (data.status != 'OK') {
        alert("ERROR " + data.message);
        return;
    }
    if (data.message) {
        alert(data.message);
        // do not return
    }
    // other
}
```

So you'd start with a submit script like this (*I repeat, this is awkward. You really want to do this with proper logging and Firebug!*), commenting the various jqExit's once you check they code is working up to any given point:

```
<?php
    function jqExit($status, $message = false) {
        $packet = array('status' => $status);
        if (false !== $message) {
            $packet['message'] = $message;
        }
        exit(json_encode($packet));
    }

    jqExit('ERROR', "Alpha - got POST");

    // Connect to database

    jqExit('ERROR', "Bravo - connected to DB");

    // Decode and validate POST

    jqExit('ERROR', "Charlie - data ready");

    // Perform update

    if (...update failed...) {
        jqExit('ERROR', "reason why it failed");
    }

    // Finally everything is OK
    jqExit('OK');
?>
```

Comment: I don't know where the problem exactly lies, it displays the Success message and that's it

Comment: If it displays the success-message the ajax-request is performed, which means the problem lies in the PHP.

Comment: Yes. As I said, "success" just means that the script did receive *something*. But you need to know *what*, and how it did react. I'll add to the answer.

Comment: I got it working, thankyou. Brilliant answer :)

Comment: @Iserni sorry to bring this back up, but how would I access a certain field from the from? I tried $_POST['notes'] however that didn't work. I know that my query works because I added a static value and that worked fine. Thankyou.

Comment: The way you did it is correct. Maybe you were trying to do something with the value, and there was the error. For example, you want to insert it into a MySQL field, you need to use PDO or escape the value in case it contains, say, quote ' ' marks.